# XSLT xmlXPathCompOpEval: function new not found

Tags: java, xml, date, xslt

I am trying to execute my xsl file and getting an error which says function new not found.

Command to execute my xsl:  `xsltproc GetRequestTransformation.xsl xsltTest.xml`

Whenever I try to execute the above command in my Linux machine, I get the below error :

```
compilation error: file GetRequestTransformation.xsl line 5 element stylesheet
xsl:version: only 1.0 features are supported
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function new not found
XPath error : Unregistered function
xmlXPathCompOpEval: parameter error
runtime error: file GetRequestTransformation.xsl line 15 element variable
Failed to evaluate the expression of variable 'currentDate'.
```

Here is my XSLT file **GetRequestTransformation.xsl** :

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='2.0'
        xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
        xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" xmlns:SimpleDateFormat="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"
        xmlns:Date="java.util.Date" exclude-result-prefixes="java SimpleDateFormat Date">
        <xsl:template match="/">
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
                    <soapenv:Header/>
                    <soapenv:Body>
                        <max:CreateWS_INCID_AFEC_TB>
                            <max:WS_INCID_AFEC_TBSet>
                                <max:DURACION>
                                    <xsl:variable name="affectedFinish" select='/tTroubleticket/alarms/tTroubleticketalarm/clearDate' />
                                    <xsl:variable name="affectedStart" select='/tTroubleticket/alarms/tTroubleticketalarm/activationDate' />
                                    <xsl:variable name="currentDate" select="SimpleDateFormat:format(SimpleDateFormat:new('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), Date:new() />
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="$affectedFinish != null">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$affectedFinish - $affectedStart" />
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$currentDate - $affectedStart" />
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </max:DURACION>
                            </max:WS_INCID_AFEC_TBSet>
                        </max:CreateWS_INCID_AFEC_TB>
                    </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>
            </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Mapping XML file **xsltTest.xml**:

```
<tTroubleticket>
<alarms>
        <tTroubleticketalarm>
                <activationDate>2015-04-01 12:42:22.0</activationDate>
                <clearDate>null</clearDate>
        </tTroubleticketalarm>
    </alarms>
</tTroubleticket>
```

Could you please try to find out the issue with my xsl file. Am I missing anything before I execute that command? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java extension function mechanism you're trying to use is specific to the Xalan Java XSLT processor and will not work in `xsltproc` (which is not written in Java). If you want to execute this stylesheet from the command line you will need to download Xalan and run its [command line tool](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/commandline.html)

```
java -cp xalan.jar:serializer.jar org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -XSL GetRequestTransformation.xsl -IN xsltTest.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 14, after `Date:new()`: close the parentheses and the quotes:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentDate" select="SimpleDateFormat:format(SimpleDateFormat:new('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), Date:new())" />
```

---

### Edit:

Ian Roberts' eyes are sharper than mine; I skimmed over the command line section and concentrated on your XSLT code only, assuming it's being run by a processor written in Java (i.e. either Xalan or Saxon).

FWIW, you don't need to use Java to get the current date: the EXSLT `date:date()` and `date:time()` extension functions are supported by both libxslt and Xalan. libxslt also supports `date:date-time()` and `date:difference()`.

Comment: Could you please tell me what all needs to be done in order to configure EXSLT ?

Comment: Just declare the relevant namespace and use the function - see: http://exslt.org/date/index.html

Comment: Do I need to add any jars in the classpath ?

Comment: I believe I should download the zip file provided in the above link you shared. But unfortunately the files are not available on GItHub

Comment: No, what I just said is it. -- **P.S.** *jar* and *classpath* are Java speak. This is confusing. Are you in fact using Java for this? As Ian mentioned, xsltproc is not Java; it invokes the libxslt processor which is written in C.